# modal forms and shared data,

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, shared-objects

I've written a couple of c# forms applications which use a lot of the same data/objects which would better be combined. I realise I could use modal forms to launch each of these but where should I state .dll's and other resources, on the parent form? or on each other form where necessary?

Comment: I don't understand why the fact that a form is modal is relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The things you can use:

- static objects;
- singleton pattern;
- pass objects in forms constructors or properties;
- use inherited forms, keeping in the base all common properties.

Comment: To show a thing, you show the thing. To show a pattern, you show a bunch of other things because you *can't* show the pattern itself. Therefore a pattern is not a thing in the same sense that a thing is a thing.

Comment: This would make total sense in French. :)

Comment: a thing is not imperatively material.

Comment: But a pattern *is* imperatively non-material, yes?

Comment: What I say that a thing could be immaterial, so a pattern.

Comment: I will remove my comments, any sense .

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution may seem like using singleton/static objects; but it may cause trouble in case you have multiple users accessing your business objects.

The other thing that you can do is that you add your objects in Master Form, and call master form objects from child forms.

Just as a side note, you can also think about a [3 tier approach](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/three_tier_architecture.aspx):

1. The data layer, if any that you have.
2. Your business objects; the business logic layer.
3. The presentation layer;

Access your BLL via your presentation and change whatever, wherever(which Form), and however(defined in your BLL). Use data layer to manipulate your business.

Comment: @serhio: Precisely business/domain logic layer(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic_layer); a part of multi-tier architecture(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).